# Symfony can't load FieldVote

Tags: php, symfony, crud, classnotfoundexception

I created a CRUD from an existing entity, everything went fine until I went to see the result, where I'm getting the following error :

(Using Symfony 3)

> Attempted to load class "FieldVote" from namespace "Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Voter".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
>   500 Internal Server Error - ClassNotFoundException

I don't know what to do with this, since no one seem to ever have this problem, nor where to find what caused it.

Anyway, here are the snippets from my entity and my controller :

**MissionBundle.php**

```
<?php

namespace MissionBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use MissionBundle\Entity\Mission;
use MissionBundle\Form\MissionType;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

/**
 * Mission controller.
 *
 * @Route("/mission")
 */
class MissionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all Mission entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="mission_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $missions = $em->getRepository('MissionBundle:Mission')->findAll();

        return $this->render('mission/index.html.twig', array(
            'missions' => $missions,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Mission entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="mission_new")
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_RECRUTEUR') or has_role('ROLE_RESPONSABLE')")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $mission = new Mission();
        $form = $this->createForm('MissionBundle\Form\MissionType', $mission);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($mission);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('mission_show', array('id' => $mission->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('mission/new.html.twig', array(
            'mission' => $mission,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a Mission entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="mission_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function showAction(Mission $mission)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($mission);

        return $this->render('mission/show.html.twig', array(
            'mission' => $mission,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Mission entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="mission_edit")
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_RECRUTEUR') or has_role('ROLE_RESPONSABLE')")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Mission $mission)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($mission);
        $editForm = $this->createForm('MissionBundle\Form\MissionType', $mission);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($mission);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('mission_edit', array('id' => $mission->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('mission/edit.html.twig', array(
            'mission' => $mission,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a Mission entity.
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_RECRUTEUR') or has_role('ROLE_RESPONSABLE')")
     * @Route("/{id}", name="mission_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, Mission $mission)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($mission);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($mission);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('mission_index');
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a Mission entity.
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_RECRUTEUR') or has_role('ROLE_RESPONSABLE')")
     * @param Mission $mission The Mission entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm(Mission $mission)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('mission_delete', array('id' => $mission->getId())))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

**Mission.php (entity)**

```
<?php
// src/MissionBundle/Entity/Mission.php
namespace MissionBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
Class Mission{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $intitule;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateDepot;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $dateDebut;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $dateFin;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $visibilite;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isConnected;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set intitule
     *
     * @param string $intitule
     *
     * @return Mission
     */
    public function setIntitule($intitule)
    {
        $this->intitule = $intitule;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get intitule
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIntitule()
    {
        return $this->intitule;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Mission
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateDepot
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateDepot
     *
     * @return Mission
     */
    public function setDateDepot($dateDepot)
    {
        $this->dateDepot = $dateDepot;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateDepot
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateDepot()
    {
        return $this->dateDepot;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateDebut
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateDebut
     *
     * @return Mission
     */
    public function setDateDebut($dateDebut)
    {
        $this->dateDebut = $dateDebut;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateDebut
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateDebut()
    {
        return $this->dateDebut;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateFin
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateFin
     *
     * @return Mission
     */
    public function setDateFin($dateFin)
    {
        $this->dateFin = $dateFin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateFin
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateFin()
    {
        return $this->dateFin;
    }

    /**
     * Set visibilite
     *
     * @param boolean $visibilite
     *
     * @return Mission
     */
    public function setVisibilite($visibilite)
    {
        $this->visibilite = $visibilite;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get visibilite
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getVisibilite()
    {
        return $this->visibilite;
    }

    /**
     * Set isConnected
     *
     * @param boolean $isConnected
     *
     * @return Mission
     */
    public function setIsConnected($isConnected)
    {
        $this->isConnected = $isConnected;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isConnected
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsConnected()
    {
        return $this->isConnected;
    }
}
```

There isn't any mention of vote or anything inside the codes, so I don't know what it needs to load FieldVote, or, what keeps it from loading it.
Does anyone have an idea?
I must precise that if I go on mission/new, or mission/{id} or whatever, it works perfectly fine.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

totally looks like a symfony core bug to me. There is no Acl directory in https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security in branch 3.*

Actually, this directory was removed in 2.7, so no component post 2.8 should use it. Maybe you should report it to SensioLabs.

To get rid of this bug, you can avoid using @Security Annotation, and use the security service instead and test for authorization inside the controller itself :

```
if (false === $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_RECRUTEUR')) {
    ....
}
```